# completeSVMForVMAffectedByKB1003874.pl

Tags: vmware-esx

So, had a client svmotion a vm to a new lun and use thin provisioning and hit this bug. figured simple enough, su to root and run the script here to fix.

http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1003874

Unfortunately, hitting this issue below and no idea how to fix

VMware ESX Server 3.5.0 build-64607

Can't locate VMware/VIRuntime.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.0/i386-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.0 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.0/i386-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.0 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.0/i386-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.0 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.0/i386-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.0 .) at completeSVMForVMAffectedByKB1003874.pl line 5.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at completeSVMForVMAffectedByKB1003874.pl line 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you apply the recommended patch?

(btw, that's 12q's in 24hrs - do you sleep? have you heard of twitter?)

Comment: Thanks for the answers, Philip. Actually few people are using this profile - my friend asked me for mine.

Comment: That would explain it, is one of them 'Mags'? he asks the same type of question very frequently too.

Comment: You didn't answer the important question....